# Find a formula for this sequence (and prove it).

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

This is a 2 part problem.

**Part I**

I need help finding a formula for this sequence of numbers:

$$\frac{1} {1\times 2} + \frac {1} {2\times3} + \cdots + \frac {1} {n(n+1)}$$

**Part II**

I need to prove the formula conjectured in Part I.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac1{k(k+1)}=\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}$$

Now telescope.

Comment: I remember briefly touching Seq/Series in Calculus II, but glossing over the material (it was a 5-week summer course) and not retaining anything.

Comment: By asking for a formula is this problem requesting that I write it in summation notation?  I don't see why re-writing the problem as telescope series matters, as a formula for the nth term was already provided.

Comment: @Thomas: You don’t really need to remember anything. Write out the expansion of the sum for a few small values of $n$ and see what happens. For instance, $$\frac1{2\cdot3}+\frac1{3\cdot4}=\left(\frac11-\color{red}{\frac12}\right)+ \left(\color{red}{\frac12}-\frac13\right)=\frac11-\frac13\;.$$

Comment: It looks like every term cancels out (I mean, a positive is added to a negative... I don't know the right words to describe it) - and, all I'm left with is 1?

Comment: @Thomas: That’s not quite right: notice the $-\frac13$ as well. Try it with a few more, $n=3$ and $n=4$, say. // To answer your previous question, they want a closed form, one **not** involving a summation.

Comment: I mean, (k+1)-1 / (k+1).  Is that correct?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, it is, though I'd have written $1-\frac 1{k+1}$ or perhaps $\frac{k}{k+1}$.

Comment: Is the proof just showing telescopic series?

Comment: @Thomas: I would prove by induction on $n$ that the $n$-th sum is $1-\frac 1{n+1}$.

Comment: @Thomas: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

the $r$ term $$T_r=\frac1{r(r+1)}=\frac{r+1-r}{r(r+1)}=\frac1r-\frac1{r+1}$$

Put $r=1,2,\cdots,n-1,n$ and see what happens

Do you know [Telescopic Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?

Comment: @ThomasSmith, have you derived the sum?

Comment: Everything cancels out except the 1/1 and 1 / k + 1 giving the closed formula k / k + 1.

I am now trying to prove it by induction (although I'm still learning how to do this)

Comment: @ThomasSmith, if the sum of $n$ terms is $1-\frac1{n+1}=\frac n{n+1},$ the sum of $n+1$ terms will be $\frac n{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}=?$

Comment: Nevermind. I see what you did here.

Comment: I ended up with (n+1)/(n+2) but I'm not sure what to do with that.

Comment: Is that the proof?  Did I just prove it through induction?

Comment: @ThomasSmith, what do you think? If the sum of $n$ terms is $\frac n{n+1},$ our proposition is $f(k)=\frac k{k+1}$ put $k=n+1$ that is what we have derived, right? So, we are done

Comment: Perfect!  I want to visit India someday!  Everybody there is so smart! (Gross generalization?  But, thanks!)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9731/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-thomas-smith)